# I have a 400 code on POST request in react hook project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm practing hook in react with a todo list project. The GET and DELETE methods work fine but when I try to post a new item the response to that is a 400 "bad request".

My project have the backend in Django and all methods in there works perfectly which makes me think that the problem is in the front.

This is my app.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Tasks from './components/tasks/Tasks';
import Form from './components/form/Form';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {

  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8000/api/todo/tasks')
      .then(res => setTodoList(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  },[])


  const deleteTask = item => {
    const erased = setTodoList(todoList.filter(el => el !== item))
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/todo/tasks/${item.id}/`)
      .then(res => erased);
  };

  const submit = item => {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/api/todo/tasks/', item)
      .then(res => setTodoList([...todoList, item]));

  };



  return (
    <div className="todo-app container">
      <h2 className="center blue-text">Listado de tareas</h2>
      <Tasks tasks={todoList} del={deleteTask}/>
      <Form saveTask={submit} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my Form component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Form.css';

const Form = ({ saveTask }) => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('')


  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    saveTask(value)
    setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Escribe una tarea</label>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="waves-effect waves-light btn buttonColor"
        >
          Crear tarea
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

I searched several places and it seems my code is correct but I can't find the problem.

I leave a capture of the response:

[image]

Comment: Check the request being made in the Devtool's "Network" tab and compare it with what your backend expects.

Comment: I noticed `http://localhost:8000/api/todo/tasks/` this link has an extra `/`. Before you are really sure it's the UI problem, you could try call this API in another tool, ex. `Postman`

Comment: windmaomao the final "/" is correct, otherwise I get 500 code. In Postman as in Django's client, all http method works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the .post() must be that way:

```
axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/api/todo/tasks/', {
        title: item,
      })
      .then(res => {
        const element = res.data
        setTodoList([...todoList, element])
      });
```

The second parameter in post function must be an object where the key is the model's attribute and the value is "item" which contain the the task's text